# Explanation two files for a kernel panic report?

Tags: kernel-panic, macos

For a monitoring tool, we are relaying on the reports generated on kernel-panic at

> "/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports"

In the past, kernel panics were reported as a file like:

> Kernel_2019-11-12-123456_computer-name.panic

However, it appear that some computers (some Catalina?) reports them as:

> .contents.panic (single file override every time)

Which links to some

> panic-full-2019-11-12-123456.1234.ips

### My questions is:

Why or when the kernel panic is reported as a single file, or as several files? Which are the conditions and the reasons for each cases?

Any hint is welcome.